# Why can I use vertex form to solve one problem but not the other

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

What is the positive value of $k$ for which the graph $y=x^2-2kx +16$ is tangent to the x-axis?

My approach to solving this question is to use vertex form to find the value of $x$. Once I have that, I can substitute that value to find the value of $k$, which is $4$.

If I try to apply that same method to this question,
[image]

I get $p=4\sqrt{3}$. The correct answer is $p = 6$. What is wrong with the way I applied my method?

Answer (score 0):

In the second problem, the graph is not tangent to the $x$-axis.  Instead, since the lowest point of the rope is at a height of $1$, the graph is tangent to the line $y=1$.  You could use the same method to solve this problem, but you would need to subtract $1$ from the quadratic first to make it tangent to the $x$-axis.

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe i miss that vital information. I was beginning to question my approach was ever right in the first place @ Eric Wofsey

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided your solution, I presume you computed the value of $k$ by completing squares. In particular, you transformed $$y = x^2-2kx+16=(x-k)^2+(16-k^2),$$
and put $y=0$ at $x=k$ to find $k=4$.

For the given problem,
$$y = \frac{x}{3}(x-p)+4 = \frac{\left(x-\frac{p}{2}\right)^2}{3}+4-\frac{p^2}{12}.$$
Now, for $x=\frac{p}{2}$, $y=1 \implies 4-\frac{p^2}{12}=1 \implies p^2=36 \implies p=6$.

You could also identify $p$ by noting that $y$ achieves its minimum when $x=3$. That is, $\frac{p}{2}=3$.

Comment: I used the vertex formula -b/2a to find x and back into the original equation. The first part, the lowest point is tangent the x-axis which makes y = 0, for the second part, y is equal to 1. All and all the method works for both problem but I missed the information about y =1 for the second part. Thankyou for taking the time to help though @ Math Lover